# Forge Viewer SVF2 PowerBI not loading

Tags: powerbi, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to load an SVF2 from ACC into Power BI but the geometry is not loading.

I'm using the following credentials options :

```
const options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction2',
            api: 'streamingV2',
            accessToken: token,
        }
```

and the viewer is stuck, like on the picture :

[image: Viewer not loading]

and in the console I got this error (I'm not sure if it's linked to forge)

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'IDBFactory': access to the Indexed Database API is denied in this context.
at LocalDbCache.open (blob:null/a4675167-582d-4db2-8834-6a5f9e63ee2e:25855:31)
at Object.doInitGeomWorker [as doOperation] (blob:null/a4675167-582d-4db2-8834-6a5f9e63ee2e:33375:18)
at WorkerMain.dispatch (blob:null/a4675167-582d-4db2-8834-6a5f9e63ee2e:32956:14)
at blob:null/a4675167-582d-4db2-8834-6a5f9e63ee2e:48870:55
```

If I switch my options to use SVF(1) it's working and the geometry is well loaded, however the dbid are not matching.

```
const options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction',
            api: 'derivativeV2',
            accessToken: token,
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Power BI disabled the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API). You might need to consult the Power BI community, but you may try to disable the svf2 cache by appending this query string parameter `disableIndexedDb=true` to your viewer app URL to see if it helps. e.g. `http://localhost:3000?disableIndexedDb=true` **(Note. just for debug purpose, do not use this option in production)**

Regarding the dbid mismatching, are you working with [MD GET properties API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/)? If yes, please include this extra request header `x-ads-derivative-format: fallback` while calling the below Model Derivative API.

- [GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET)
- [GET {urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll ask the PowerBI community for the first part. But for now the x-ads-derivative-format: fallback header is doing the job !

Comment: Is it possible to pass the disableindexeddb as parameter to the viewer initialiser function?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's unsupported in initializer as I know.

Comment: I think it might be possible to toggle this option by setting `DISABLE_INDEXED_DB` in the global scope to `true`.

Comment: What do you mean in the global scope?

Comment: @piede Adding `window.DISABLE_INDEXED_DB = true`
before the codes where you load viewer resources (JS & CSS file).

Comment: I get a: Property 'DISABLE_INDEXED_DB' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
window.indexeddb is available but have to methods to disable it

Comment: We can manually add extra properties to window like this way:
https://github.com/yiskang/aps-powerbi-tools/blob/example/svf2-support/visuals/aps-viewer-visual/src/viewer.utils.ts#L10