# Disable IndexedDB for Forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, indexeddb

Is it possible to disable IndexedDB when initialising the viewer. I have seen an option that suggest to pass it as query parameter but would it be possible to do it via the viewer initialiser function?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's unsupported, as I replied to you in the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/71701129/7745569

And please be noted that the query string `disableIndexedDb=true` is for debugging only, not for production use. If you want to use it, please use it at your own risk.